# Capture screen using FFMPEG on a headless VPS

Tags: ubuntu, x11, ffmpeg

I need a solution to run a graphical application on a Ubuntu VPS and capture the screen using FFMPEG software.

the steps I tried already:

```
###Create a virtual desktop
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1920x1080x24

## Connect this shell to a virtual desktop
export DISPLAY=:1

#Start browser. It streams to a virtual desktop connected. This could be any program.
google-chrome-stable --disable-gpu https://example.com/

#Capture screen output to a file
export DISPLAY=:1
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :1.0+0,0 output.mp4
```

This looks like working but the output file comes empty.
I need somebody who can reliably tell me how to run graphical apps on a VPS and capture the screen to a file.
Later ffmpeg will stream the video but for now, I just want to solve one problem at a time.

Comment: are you sure `:0.0` is correct given your `DISPLAY=:1`

Comment: I didn't tell you anything so you couldn't have tried anything I said

Answer (score 0):

It started to work after I installed

```
  sudo apt-get install x11-apps
```